# Return a reference via member-function in C++ fast than returning a copy?

Tags: c++, avr

Is there a performance difference, when I use references for get-functions? I feel, that with Arduino my program runs 6.6 % slower since I encapsulated my public member variables into public get-functions. On the other hand I want to have the comfort to use const.

```
class aClass {
private: 
  aStruct bar;

public:
  aStruct &getBar_fast() {
    return bar;
  }

  aStruct getBar_slow() const {
    return bar;
  }
};
```

Comment: You might be better avoiding getter altogether if you really want encapsulation.

Comment: You feel it's 6.6% slower? Man, your senses are bloody accurate. :)

Comment: Depending on a struct size. For large structs reference works faster.

Comment: returning a non-const reference to your member breaks encapsulation and should be avoided in general.

Comment: `const aStruct& getBar_slow() const`

Answer (score 0):

When you are returning a reference you don't need to go through the copy constructor.

If you are returning like you are doing getBar_slow() the copy constructor of aStruct will be called (thus extra time).

When using the first getBar_fast() , any change done to the returned structure will be visible inside the function.

When using the 2nd getBar_slow() , any change done to the returned structure will not be visible inside the function.

Something else worth mentioning (if you are after performance) is that inlining your functions will add a bit of extra speed (but this might already been done by the compiler if you declared the body in the header file).

Answer (score 0):

It is slower if and only if any of the following conditions hold:

- `sizeof(aStruct) > sizeof(void*)`
- `aStruct` has an explicit copy-constructor

Comment: Good advice to return large struct by reference if you can, but it's not such a clear-cut rule. Returning a larger struct by value can be faster than by reference. It depends too much on compiler optimizations for such a sweeping statement.

Comment: @NeilKirk: Thank you for pointing that out. Indeed, the specific compiler in use, as well as optimization flags, may affect the final outcome in terms of runtime performance. In my answer, I am referring purely to coding issues. The first condition yields a larger mem-copy operation. The second condition yields an additional function-call. Now, for example, if the explicit copy-constructor is identical to an implicit (default) copy-constructor, then the compiler may choose to "opt it out of the code". But again, I was referring strictly to the code itself. Thanks again :)

Comment: In the first, a larger copy may be faster than indirectly accessing the data in the struct through a reference. In the second case, simple copy constructors can be inlined by the compiler.

Comment: @NeilKirk: For the first, you're assuming that the data will be accessed indirectly after the function returns, when it might actually be sent to some other function by reference. For the second, even if the copy-constructor is inlined by the compiler, if it does more than just copying the attributes of the structure (which is a reasonable assumption to make, otherwise it would be pointless to define such copy-constructor in the first place), then it's still going to take longer to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, returning a reference is faster than value, because it will construct the `aStruct` and return to the caller.

If the struct is large or have dynamic allocated memory (and it has copy-constructor), it will be slower.

If the getter object shall not be changed, you'd better to add `const` like below:

```
  const aStruct &getBar_fast() {
    return bar;
  }
```

or better to

```
  const aStruct* getBar_fast() {
    return &bar;
  }
```

Comment: Your get functions should also be const. Why is the second better?

Comment: Yes, the function could be const. The second returns pointer so it could be cast to `const void*` and pass to other functions. In some cases we need to do this. But it's just my preferred way, you may consider const reference is better...

Comment: Why can't you cast a reference to void* if you need to? Also using void* should be avoided if possible. I never need it unless writing very low-level code.

Answer (score 0):

the comfort of using const can also be achieved by implementing the getter in this way:

```
const aStruct &getBar_fast()const {
  return bar;
}
```

this returns a const reference that that prohibits changes of the referenced object but also makes no copy of the data.

This also enforces you to keep your const correctness of the `aStruct` class member functions.